# The code does not return to its original state after execution when we remove the check box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I encountered a problem. My code runs only once. When I uncheck the checkbox, I want it to return to its original state, but this doesn't happen. Thank you for your help.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">
    <p id="lable">Hello !!!</p>
</body>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var checked = true;
        var unchecked = false;
        if (checked) {
            document.getElementById('lable').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            document.getElementById('lable').style.color = "rgb(134, 134, 134)";
        } else if (unchecked) {
            document.getElementById('lable').style.color = 'black';
        }

    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to show in function what is the state of your checkBox. 
Try this code :

```
    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ch"onclick="myFunction()">
    <p id="lable">Hello !!!</p>
</body>
<script>
    function myFunction() {


        if (document.getElementById("ch").checked) {
            document.getElementById('lable').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            document.getElementById('lable').style.color = "rgb(134, 134, 134)";
        } else{
            document.getElementById('lable').style.color = 'black';
            document.getElementById('lable').style.textDecoration = null;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Instead of putting a code only, explain it in order to be sure the person who asked the question understood your approach!
Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning checked as a boolean (true or false) .
if(true) and if(false) doesn't check if the checkbox is checked or no!

It's done as follows:

**HTML**: You assign an ID to the checkbox input element

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" onclick="myFunction()">
```

**JS**: you get the element by it's ID and check if it's checked or no.

```
mycheckbox=document.getElementByID("mycheckbox");
if(mycheckbox.checked == true){
 //your code here
}
else{
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic of myFunction() is wrong. Every time it will go to `if` block only as you are setting `var checked = true;`
Try this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxId" onclick="myFunction()">
    <p id="lable">Hello !!!</p>
</body>
<script>
    function myFunction() {

        var isChecked = document.getElementById("checkBoxId").checked;
        if (isChecked) {
            document.getElementById('lable').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            document.getElementById('lable').style.color = "rgb(134, 134, 134)";
        } else{
            document.getElementById('lable').style.textDecoration = 'none';
            document.getElementById('lable').style.color = 'black';
        }

    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the checked status from the actual dom node instead of hardcoding a value.

```
var checked = document.querySelector('input').checked;
```

There are a couple of other problems in here. Instead of using a `<p>` tag you should be using a `<label>`.  You could also rewrite the javascript to be strictly css.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">Hello !!!</label>
</div>

input:checked + label {
    color: rgb(134, 134, 134)
    textDecoration: 'line-through'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are not associated to the checkbox.
Look at this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp
it should help you !

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">
    <p id="lable">Hello !!!</p>
</body>
<script>
    var checked = false;
    function myFunction() {          
        if (checked) {
            document.getElementById('lable').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            document.getElementById('lable').style.color = "rgb(134, 134, 134)";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('lable').style.textDecoration = '';
            document.getElementById('lable').style.color = 'black';
        }
        checked = !checked;    
    }
</script>
</html>
```